# Can "diario" and "periódico" be used interchangeably?

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras

I just stumbled upon "diario" and "periódico" while extending my vocabulary. Both mean *newspaper* in English.

Is there any context in which just one fits? Can they be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- *Periódico* means periodic, that is, periodic, regular, recurring.
- *Diario* means daily.

Hence, *diario* is something more strict that *periódico* because the first refers to a daily periodic.

However, currently both are used almost interchangeably and so DRAE states:

> **[periódico, ca](http://dle.rae.es/?w=peri%C3%B3dico&m=form&o=h)**
>
> Del lat. periodĭcus, y este del gr. περιοδικός periodikós.
>
> 1. adj. Que guarda período determinado.
> 2. adj. Que se repite con frecuencia a intervalos determinados.
> 3. adj. Dicho de un impreso: Que se publica con determinados intervalos de tiempo. U. m. c. s. m.
>
> ...
>
> 6. m. Publicación que sale diariamente.
>
> **[diario, ria](http://dle.rae.es/?w=diario&o=h)**
>
> Del lat. diarium.
>
> 1. adj. Correspondiente a todos los días. Rutina, comida diaria.
> 2. m. Relato de lo que ha sucedido día por día. Escribe un diario íntimo. Los diarios de Jovellanos.
> 3. m. Libro o cuaderno donde se lleva un diario.
> 4. m. **Periódico que se publica todos los días.**

I cannot think in any periódico that is not diario. You can find semanarios, etc, but nowadays I haven't heard of the use of periódico to refer to something that is not a diario.

Comment: So formally no but informally yes?

Comment: @corsiKa exactly.

Answer (score 6):

`Periódico` is a newspaper published periodically, with the period not specified. But also can be used as `diario`. According to RAE:

> 3 adj. Dicho de un impreso: Que se publica con determinados intervalos de tiempo. U. m. c. s. m.
>   6 m. Publicación que sale diariamente.

`Diario` is a newspaper published daily. According to RAE:

> 3. m. Periódico que se publica todos los días.

Therefore, a `diario` is a `periódico`, and both can be used to refer to a newspaper published on a daily basis.

You also have the word `semanario` to specify a publication published every week.

Answer (score 2):

You can use both of them as they mean almost the same, but I would suggest you to use **periódico** because any **periódico** is a **diario** but there are other type of **diarios** that are not **periódicos** like a little girl's diary.